# Error while importing component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

It could be a simple mistake. But I'm a newbie in this area. I get a Syntax Error on Unexpected Token here:

```
component: () => import('@/layouts/default.vue'),
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: change "@" for a dot "."

Comment: would it be a ';' at the end rather than ','?

Comment: its actually in a package that I used. So they had it working.

Comment: The @ actually finds the right path for the component.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a component into another module/component then use this at the top of your file:

```
import MyComponent from '@/layouts/default.vue'
```

...assuming you have exported ***MyComponent*** as the **default** export in your *default.vue* file.

You can change ***MyComponent*** to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using stand alone components.  In that case, include `export default` in your `default.vue` file and then `import DefaultComponent from '@/layouts/default.vue` at the top of the file. Then, include the DefaultComponent in the Components section.

### Default.vue

```
<template>
  <p>{{hi}}</p>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    data: function(){
      hi: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
</script>
<style
</style>
```

### Main.vue

```
<template>
  <default-component></default-component>
</template>
<script>
  import DefaultComponent from '@layouts/default.vue';

  export default{
    components: {
      'default-component': DefaultComponent
    }
  }
</script>
<style
</style>
```